# Does feature scaling hurt performance of a classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-extraction

Why is my classifier's performance dropping on average by 1% F1 score when I scale the features? I was expecting to improve the performance. I am using scikit-learn fro this. Here is how I do it:

```
scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler(with_mean=False).fit(X_features)

X_features_scaled =  scaler.transform(X_features)
```

Comment: Please supply the data and metrics before and after scaling.  It's likely an artifact of your data shape and model type.  Scaling is a general aid to algorithms that converge by successive approximation, such as linear regression; or those that depend on comparable effect of dimensional spread, such as k-means.  Those that work by direct computation, such as linear SVM, are less susceptible to range variations between the dimensions.

Comment: The data is text. I am doing classification. I am using various features which includes tf*idf, lexicon and linguistic features. My algorithm is linear SVM. Performance is .84 and .83 F1 score before and after scaling respectively.

Comment: Doesn't your model training routine return a set of metrics concerning the model's creation?  I was hoping for that -- I don't read them fluently by any means, but I'd hoped they might provide the critical clue.  I _did_ see your original F1 figures.